# Heroku non-volatile memory for python web application

Tags: python, heroku, storage, plotly-dash

I deployed a toy python web-application written in dash framework on Heroku.

Since I am using the free plan, after 30 min of inacivity, the app sleeps and then on next access - and since it is an [ephemeral filesystem](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), it is booted from scratch.

I want to maintain some stats (2 `int` variables) in the code across re-boots - is there any way to do this by NOT using Postgres or any other relational database?

I don't want to keep the app awake, just looking for a way to avoid using database, if at all possible.

App in question: 
https://dash-on-heroku.herokuapp.com

Comment: No. You should use a database.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping to find a way to skip the `postgres` dependency for this simple case. Is there any other database you can recommend, other than postgres for my need?

Comment: Redis is good at this kind of thing, as a simple key-value store.

Comment: but isn't redis volatile (in-memory) ? won't i lose the content after a reboot ?

Comment: It's not in the memory of your instance, but a separate add-on. It won't reboot. But if you need to be absolutely sure, it can be conducted with various types of persistence.

Comment: got it, will try it out (still new to this :) ). thanks for answering my questions!